# Remove "Send Image..." from Firefox right-click menu

Tags: firefox, context-menu

I would like to remove the Send Image... option when right-clicking on an image in Firefox. I *never* use it and it's very annoying when accidentally clicked.

Any ideas how? I'm sure it's possible, but I think I need to add a line to some file, and I don't know where or what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**The Menu Editor Plugin**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/710)
Or if you want to know how: [How to Modify Firefox Context Menus](http://www.rdrop.com/~half/Creations/Writings/TechNotes/firefox.menus.html)

Have fun!

Comment: If you're feeling really adventurous, you can use the DOM Inspector plugin (http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6622) together with the Stylish plugin (http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108) to hide it. You can also use this combination to manually customize the look and feel of all SORTS of parts of the window. As well as stylish allowing you to customize the look and feel of ANY website.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [menu editor](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/menu-editor/) extension to quickly hide the options you don't want. But be aware: it's not as permanent and update resilient as the other solutions and it tends to shuffle some options around when disabled/enabled the extension, using the "reset all" will put them all back in their default places.